# Moving data from Mysql to Db2

Tags: mysql, database, db2

Has anyone worked on moving data from MySQL to Db2, I am looking for options to move data from mysql to Db2.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you just moving data or doing a migration? because queries could change and you have to configure DB2 in order to ease this procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try IBM Data Movement Tool.

Please refer: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/

Comment: link no longer works

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0807patel/

Comment: Neither link works anymore. I am currently looking for this tool, could I trouble you to share the .jar if your have it?